# reduce number of points in a curve

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

[image]

There is given curve with (x,y) coordinates. I am working on reducing no. of points in falling curve using tolerance check between two points `(y2-y1)/y1` if this tolerance is below predefined value `0.01` then consider that point otherwise remove that point.

By doing this I am getting dense points at bottom with respect to top of curve.

How can I have dense curve at top of curve to like bottom.

Some Sample Points :

```
9.99E-10    1.17E+00
1.50E-09    7.53E-01
2.00E-09    1.77E-01
2.50E-09    1.61E-02
```

Answer (score 2):

You are just comparing changes in height, but what seems to be more important are changes in slope. So try the following:

Consider the first three points:

If the slope from 1st to 2nd is almost equal to that from 1st to 3rd, remove the 2nd point. Repeat.

If the slope changes considerably keep the 2nd point and make it the new 1st point for a new triple.

Comment: This is essentially what my answer says, which is to use the instantaneous change in slope (`y2 - y1`) to determine how many points to use in the quadrature.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the slope of the curve to determine how many sample points you need.  One way to do this is to compute the instantaneous derivative at each point, which can be approximated as `(y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)`, where the two points are very close to each other.  You can compute this term for the entire curve on a grid with equally spaces of `(x2 - x1)`.  Then you can see that your original approach was not far off, and `y2 - y1` can be used to approximate the slope, and therefore how many sampling points you need, for a fixed width sample of the curve.

By using `y2 - y1`, the middle portion of your curve would have the greatest number of points for sampling.  This intuitively makes sense, because the function changes the fastest in the middle.  And at the edge of the curve, you would need relatively fewer samples as the slope does not change much.

Comment: using 'y2/y1' is not reducing points, I used tolerance as 0.01

Comment: Sorry I had intended to write `y2 - y1`.  This means you add more points when the slope of the function changes more quickly, which is what you want.